# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' in AWS Lambda (Node 14.x)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So currently i'm developing a simple login and register system using AWS, but then I encountered this problem in AWS Lambda while testing my backend in postman, the full error code is shown below

```json
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
    "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:222:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:300:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:34)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)",
        "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)",
        "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
    ]
}
```

Im currently running Node 14.x in my AWS Lambda, some of my codes are shown below

**Index.js**

```js
const healthPath = '/health';
const registerPath = '/register';
const loginPath = '/login';
const verifyPath = '/verify';

const registerService = require('./services/register');
const loginService = require('./services/login');
const verifyService = require('./services/verify');
const util = require('./utils/util');


export const handler = async(event) => {
    console.log('Request Event : ', event);
    let response;
    switch(true){
        case event.httpMethod === 'GET'&& event.path === healthPath:
            response = util.buildResponse(200);
            break;
        case event.httpMethod === 'POST'&& event.path === registerPath:
            const registerBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
            response = await registerService.register(registerBody);
            break;
        case event.httpMethod === 'POST'&& event.path === loginPath:
            const loginBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
            response = await loginService.login(loginBody);
            break;
        case event.httpMethod === 'POST'&& event.path === verifyPath:
            const verifyBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
            response = verifyService.verify(verifyBody);
            break;
        default:
        response = util.buildResponse(404, 'Not Found');
    }
    return response;
};
```

**Register.js**

```js
const util = require('../utils/util');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
    region: 'eu-north-1'
})

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const userTable = 'userData';

async function register(userInfo) {
    const name = userInfo.name;
    const email = userInfo.email;
    const username = userInfo.username;
    const password = userInfo.password;
    //check if all fields are filled by user
    if(!username || !name || !email || !password){
        return util.buildResponse(401, {
            message: 'All fields are required!'
        })
    }
    //check if username already exist or not
    const dynamoUser = await getUser(username.toLowerCase().trim());
    if(dynamoUser && dynamoUser.username){
        return util.buildResponse(401,{
            message: 'Username already taken'
        })
    }
    //encrypt the password
    const encryptedPw = bcrypt.hashSync(password.trim(), 10);
    //creating new user object
    const user = {
        name: name,
        email : email,
        username: username.toLowerCase().trim(),
        password: encryptedPw
    }
    //saving user to database
    const saveUserResponse = await saveUser(user);
    //if there is an error
    if(!saveUserResponse){
        return util.buildResponse(403,{
            message: 'Server Error! Pelase try again later!'
        })
    }
    //if successful
    return util.buildResponse(200,{
        username:username
    })
}

async function getUser(username) {
    const params = {
        TableName: userTable,
        Key: {
            username: username
        }
    }
    return await dynamodb.get(params).promise().then(response => {
        return response.Item;
    }, error => {
        console.error('There is an error retrieving user!', error);
    })
}

async function saveUser(user){
    const params = {
        TableName: userTable,
        Item: user
    }
    return await dynamodb.put(params).promise().then(() => {
        return true;
    }, error => {
        console.error('There is an error saving user!', error);
    });
}

exports.register = register;
```

I tried to change the export code from exports to module.exports, upgrading the node version to 18.x, adding "type": "module" in package.json but it results in another error (didn't solve the problem) any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like you're mixing `require()`-style module syntax with ES6 module syntax; they are not compatible.

Comment: first of all, thank you for the response. If i want to use require, which other syntax do i need to change, i tried to change 'require' to 'import' but i got an error because of the aws-sdk, so i need to use require()

Comment: So with the old CommonJS module system, you use `require()` to import a module, and then set `module.exports = { something }`, or `exports.something = something` to export.

Comment: I think i used that code to export something from another codes beside index, i wrote exports.register = register; in the end of my register code to export the register function but i still got the error

Comment: @Pointy i just solved the problem by changing the index export module, i didnt realize that i wrote export const on the index file, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your error says

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'"
```

so try changing export const handler to module.exports.handler